# How would I create this extrusion in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, designers

It's a warp effect with a 3d letter depth/extrusion. I've tried the 3d extrusion effect, but it's not the right perspective. Is there a trick to get the extruded 'infinity' text behind the letters?

[image: text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to apply a bulge to your text, I like to Make With Warp.

[image: warp]

Bulge it

[image: bulge]

Then extrude it

[image: extrude]

The key to this effect is the **Perspective** setting.

Comment: You beat me to it ;) the settings for 3D bevel are -3.5, 0, 0, Perspective  79, Extrude 1129 pt. These are rough estimates.

Comment: @AndrewH yea, the settings will depend on the size/spacing of the font and the desired effect, but I was just getting them pointed in the right direction :)